# Mobile Theme not loading from mobile client

Tags: magento-1.9, theme, mobile

I know this has been asked a million times (I've looked through the threads!), but I'm having a curious issue with Magento.

The issue I'm having seems to be that, following what I did before, and suggestions from other threads, the mobile theme isn't loading.. instead its loading the main site, which isn't great on mobile. I've made sure to clear cache after making the change...

Magento ver. 1.9.1.0

Exception/Theme setup:

Matched expression:
iPhone|iPod|BlackBerry|Palm|Googlebot-Mobile|Mobile|mobile|mobi|Windows Mobile|Safari Mobile|Android|Opera Mini

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Got it Solved! Settings were correct, if not over done. Another mobile theme that was installed was somehow interfering. Removed it, and th e iphone theme works again.